# MS SQL Server: Dynamical create procedure / function / view / trigger in other database (sp_executesql)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, functions, view, dynamic-sql

**Problem:**

1. you want / need to use dynamic SQL to create procedure / function /
   view / trigger in other databases than the current
2. you can't specify the database name in the statement, `CREATE VIEW tempdb.dbo.v_test AS SELECT 1`; will fail with Error 166: *'CREATE/ALTER VIEW' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.*
3. the `CREATE` (or `ALTER`) statement needs to be the first in the
   batch, otherwise you'll get the error 111: *'CREATE ...' must be the
   first statement in a query batch.*. For This reason you can't simply write `USE <database>` before the `CREATE`:

```
DECLARE @create_sql NVARCHAR(max);
SET @create_sql = CONCAT('USE tempdb', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),
                         'CREATE VIEW dbo.v_test AS SELECT 1 AS n;'
                        );
EXEC (@create_sql) -- fails
-- or
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @create_sql -- fails too
```

4. you can't use `GO` inside an `EXEC()` or `EXEC sys.sp_executesql`
   statement, because it is not in the SQL standard (just a
   configurable    dummy word used inside SSMS and several other SQL
   tools), so you can't simply add it between the USE and the CREATE command in the script above as you would do it in SSMS when creating a "normal" deployment script
5. the internal procedure `sys.sp_executesql` exists in every database and executes the given command in its own database, but there may be many (e.g. hundred) databases, so that you can't really use multiple `IF` statements to "hardcode" where you want to execute it

Comment: You forgot to ask a question but I think you want `EXEC SomeOtherDatabase.sys.sp_executesql @create_sql;`

Comment: @DanGuzman: you forgot point 5 where you don't know, which / how many databases are needed, so you can't hardcode the `EXEC SomeOtherDatabase`, because it could be any (even a database, that your coworker created 5 minutes ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You have to use a three times nested call.

1. you call `sys.sp_executesql` in the current database (e.g. master)
2. this calls `sys.sp_executesql` in the destination database (e.g. tempdb)
3. this finally calls an EXEC (@create_sql) to create the procedure / trigger / function / trigger etc.

Since the `CREATE` statement is passed throgh as variable and not as string, you don't have to worry about quotes, special chars or sql injection - **except** for the initial `CREATE` (@create_sql in the example) of course

**Example:**

```
USE master;
DECLARE @dest_db_name sysname       = 'tempdb'
      , @create_sql   NVARCHAR(max) = 'CREATE VIEW dbo.v_test AS SELECT 1 AS n;'
      , @dummy_cmd    NVARCHAR(500)
;
                                                             -- second exec        -- third exec
SET @dummy_cmd =  CONCAT('EXEC ', QUOTENAME(@dest_db_name), '.sys.sp_executesql N''EXEC (@create_sql)'', N''@create_sql NVARCHAR(MAX)'', @create_sql = @create_sql;')
     -- first exec 
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @dummy_cmd, N'@create_sql NVARCHAR(MAX)', @create_sql = @create_sql

-- control
SELECT *  FROM tempdb.dbo.v_test

-- DROP can be used with other statements in the same batch, so it is much easier and doesn't need special treatment
SET @dummy_cmd = 'USE tempdb;' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.v_test;'
EXEC (@dummy_cmd)
```

Comment: Valiant effort, but I'd personally prefer just calling `SomeOtherDatabase.sys.sp_executesql` like Dan suggesed. Nesting past level 2 can get confusing quick.

Comment: I agree, but as I just wrote to Dan, he forgot point 5 - you don't know on which database it needs to be executed / created.

Comment: Point 5 isn't exactly valid here. You can generate the `SomeOtherDatabase.sys.sp_executesql` script automatically, such as using `sys.databases` to fill in all of the database names you care about. E.g. `SELECT CONCAT([name], '.sys.sp_executesql') AS Script FROM sys.databases`.

Comment: @J.D. Yes, and than you need to use the first `sp_executesql` call in the local database to call the just created script, which calls the second `sp_executesql` in the other database, which calls an `EXEC ()` to finally create the script - as written in my solution. Or see you any way to do it in another way?

Comment: Not sure I follow. You'd only need to nest once in my suggestion. Also not sure why you'd use `EXEC` over `sp_executesql` in the final execution with either solution though?

Comment: @J.D. regarding the last `EXEC ()` instead of `sp_execute` - it just a bit of lazyness, because I don't have to pass variables, the `EXEC ()` works as well as a call of `sp_execute`. Why do you not try / post code (using my first two variables) that creates the v_test in the @dest_db without the tripple `EXEC`? To be honest, I see no way to do it.